# JSON Parse / Unexpected Token error on html content in formBuilder

Tags: javascript, php, json, formbuilder

Can anyone tell me why this results in the error below.
The JSON parses as OK, yet there seems to be something amiss.

I know the Chrome error specifically refers to the letter l at position 44 being the issue, but I don't understand why that is causing a problem. It looks to me like the HTML content is properly escaped.

FYI I am creating a form with formBuilder and then converting the JavaScript object to a JSON string and then sending it via an XMLHttpRequest using POST with the type "Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
I am then storing it in a MYSQL JSON field via PHP without doing anything to the JSON.
This error occurs when pulling the JSON from the database and feeding it to formBuilder.
I am simply reading the MYSQL data and then echoing it out, it has not been encoded/decoded/escaped or changed in anyway since it arrived.
My understanding is that it should be automatically encoded by the Ajax post and automatically decoded by PHP on arrival so there should not be any lingering changes.

**Chrome says : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 43**

**Firefox says : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 44 of the JSON data**

```
 jQuery($ => {
  var fbTemplate = document.getElementById("fb-editor");
  var options = {
    dataType: "json",
    
    formData:'[{"type": "header", "label": "<span style=\"left: 491.077px; top: 101.108px; font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.02306);\" dir=\"ltr\">ASSOCIATE MEMBERSHIP </span><span style=\"left: 754.523px; top: 101.108px; font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.04423);\" dir=\"ltr\">APPLICATION</span>", "access": false, "subtype": "h1"}, {"name": "fname", "type": "text", "label": "First Name<br>", "access": false, "subtype": "text", "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "sname", "type": "text", "label": "Surname", "access": false, "subtype": "text", "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "radio-group-1621069307908", "type": "radio-group", "label": "Sex", "other": false, "access": false, "inline": false, "values": [{"label": "Male", "value": "Male", "selected": false}, {"label": "Female", "value": "Female", "selected": false}], "required": true}, {"name": "address", "type": "text", "label": "Address", "access": false, "subtype": "text", "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "suburb", "type": "text", "label": "Suburb/Town", "access": false, "subtype": "text", "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "postcode", "type": "text", "label": "Postcode", "access": false, "subtype": "text", "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "state", "type": "select", "label": "State", "access": false, "values": [{"label": "VIC", "value": "VIC", "selected": true}, {"label": "NSW", "value": "NSW", "selected": false}, {"label": "QLD", "value": "QLD", "selected": false}], "multiple": false, "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "DOB", "type": "date", "label": "DOB", "access": false, "required": true, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "phone", "type": "text", "label": "Home Phone<br>", "access": false, "subtype": "tel", "required": false, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "molbile", "type": "text", "label": "Mobile", "access": false, "subtype": "tel", "required": false, "className": "form-control"}, {"name": "email", "type": "text", "label": "Email", "access": false, "subtype": "email", "required": true, "className": "form-control"}]',    
    onSave: function() {
      save();
    }
  };

  var formBuilder = $(fbTemplate).formBuilder(options);
```

[error_parsing_json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I1SP.png)

I'm sending the data to PHP like this:

```
   jsonformdata = JSON.stringify(formdata);
    jsonformother = JSON.stringify(formother);
    
var params = 'form=' + jsonformdata + "&other=" + jsonformother;
      var updateurl = '/Admin/save-form.php';
    
    
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        
                //console.log("array " + formdata);
console.log("Posted " + params);
 console.log("Got back " + xhttp.responseText);
  window.alert("Your changes were saved.");
  document.getElementById('messagesresult').innerHTML="Your changes were saved";
    document.getElementById('messagesresult').style.background="green";

  setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('messagesresult').innerHTML="";
                 document.getElementById('messagesresult').style.background="white";

             }, 5000);

  
       
     }
   };

   xhttp.open("POST", updateurl, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   xhttp.send(params);
    
   
   
  }
```

After further testing I found that if I remove the first formBuilder item from the JSON there is no longer any error.

The code for that first item in the form is shown below:

```
{"type": "header", "label": "<span style=\"left: 491.077px; top: 101.108px; font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.02306);\" dir=\"ltr\">ASSOCIATE MEMBERSHIP </span><span style=\"left: 754.523px; top: 101.108px; font-size: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.04423);\" dir=\"ltr\">APPLICATION</span>", "access": false, "subtype": "h1"}
```

This passes all the JSON validators, it has no hidden characters and is encoded according to the specs as far as I can tell.

Comment: Check if the data is being stored correctly. Take data from the database and test it in an online JSON validator. If you're sending JSON, why are you setting the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header?

Comment: As i mentioned above the JSON passes all the validators I tried. You can see the actual JSON in the code above and that also passes. I am using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded header because I am sending data via POST.

Comment: @Rolf We only see the json you _send_ to the server, not the json you retrieve from the database. Compare those. Have you tried outputting the json from the database in the browser console and validate that? As position 43/44 refers to the `\"` it could be an encoding problem.

Comment: The first code clip is copied and pasted from the browser window and it contains the JSON that comes from the database. I agree that it looks like an encoding problem but I can't see anything wrong with the encoding and this JSON was produced by JSON.Stringify. The code produced by JSON.Stringify, the code in the database and the code that ends up back shown above are all identical. And I am pretty sure that \" is the correct way to escape " in JSON.

Comment: Might be an invisible character of some sort. Try to dump the JSON once it's read from the database to see what length PHP will report and see if it matches.